# python cannot find module attribute

Tags: python, python-module

I am new to Python but not new to programming (mostly C and Java).  I have what seems to be a complete newbie problem concerning a simple module import.  I have the following:

edutil.py:

```
def parse_seq(basename: str) -> int:
    return 0
```

myprog.py:

```
import edutil

class ImageFile(object):
    def __init__(self, basename: str)
        self.base = basename
        self.seq = edutil.parse_seq(self.base)
```

There's more to the code, of course, but this is the problem part.  When I try to execute my program, I get:

AttributeError: module 'edutil' has no attribute 'parse_seq'

I don't understand why this is happening.  Most import issues seem to be related to circular dependencies, but in this case there are none since edutil.py does not (currently) import anything.

Could it be related to my use of setuputils?  I made sure to include the edutil.py file in the correct place in setup.py and even re-ran the "pip install" command just to be sure.

Comment: Try putting `print(edutil.__file__)` in there and see if the printed path is the path where you expect edutil to be.  Perhaps you have something else named edutil somewhere?

Comment: Are these the entire contents of the `edutil.py` and `myprog.py` files? There could be some sort of circular import problem going on.

Comment: How are you executing the program?

Comment: Ugh, total newbie problem.  :(  The print suggestion confirmed that I was importing the correct file.  My error turned out to be a tiny typo in my setup.py file.  Thank you for the help, though.  The print(...) bit of code will aid me later, I'm sure.

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
print(edutil.__file__)
```

to your `myprog.py` and check if you are using the correct version of your module.